# C# Regex to match single number among multiple numbers in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What regex for C# can I use that matches the a "string + some number + string + some number +string"

**Sample Inputs:**

```
Book a hotel room for 10 people  -- o/p: 10
Book a hotel room for 15 people at 10AM -- o/p: 15
Book a hotel room for 5 employees for 12 dec at 10 am -- o/p: 5
Book a hotel room in Singapore for 10 people at today -- o/p: 10
Book a hotel room for  12 dec for 10 members -- o/p: 10
```

So have to fetch how many members/people/employees for booking hotel.

Hope this makes sense

A regular expression that I could plug into C# would be fantastic

I tried below pattern but not matching.

```
[A-Za-z]*\d+\s?(people)|(memebers)|(peoples)|(member)*$
```

Comment: Try it like this `[A-Za-z]*(\d+)\s?(peoples?|members?|employees?)` https://regex101.com/r/gYw9sx/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think it would be better with `person` and `poeple` (people itself is plural form).

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Of course, you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

If your number always precedes the keyword, you might not need a regex.

Try the below code.

```
var parts = line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var index = Array.Find(parts, p => p == "member" || p == "members" || p == "people");
int count = -1;
var found = index > 0 && int.TryParse(parts[index-1], out count);
```

If `found` is true, it indicates count has a valid value which you can use later on.

Comment: You can also check for the "for" before the number

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            string[] inputs = {
                                 "Book a hotel room for 10 people  -- o/p: 10",
                                 "Book a hotel room for 15 people at 10AM -- o/p: 15",
                                 "Book a hotel room for 5 employees for 12 dec at 10 am -- o/p: 5",
                                 "Book a hotel room in Singapore for 10 people at today -- o/p: 10",
                                 "Book a hotel room for  12 dec for 10 members -- o/p: 10"
                              };

            string pattern = @"for\s+(?'count'\d+)\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)";

            foreach(string input in inputs)
            {
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
                foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>().AsEnumerable())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count : '{0}', Type : '{1}'", match.Groups["count"].Value, match.Groups["type"].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the asterix `*` after the group `(member)*` will repeat the group 0 or more times so you could omit that.

Using the `$` after member`(member)$` will only match it at the end of the string.

You could use an alternation to match either people, member with an optional `s` or employee with an optional `s`

If you want to capture the digits as well for further processing you could also use a capturing group for that part.

```
\b[A-Za-z]*(\d+)\s?(people|members?|employees?)\b
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5bA-Za-z%5d*%28%5cd%2b%29%5cs%3f%28people%7cmembers%3f%7cemployees%3f%29%5cb&i=Book+a+hotel+room+for+10+people++--+o%2fp%3a+10%0d%0aBook+a+hotel+room+for+15+people+at+10AM+--+o%2fp%3a+15%0d%0aBook+a+hotel+room+for+5+employees+for+12+dec+at+10+am+--+o%2fp%3a+5%0d%0aBook+a+hotel+room+in+Singapore+for+10+people+at+today+--+o%2fp%3a+10%0d%0aBook+a+hotel+room+for++12+dec+for+10+members+--+o%2fp%3a+10+) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/6Bh2qY)

[image]

For example

```
string pattern = @"\b[A-Za-z]*(\d+)\s?(people|members?|employees?)\b";
string input = @"Book a hotel room for 10 people  -- o/p: 10
Book a hotel room for 15 people at 10AM -- o/p: 15
Book a hotel room for 5 employees for 12 dec at 10 am -- o/p: 5
Book a hotel room in Singapore for 10 people at today -- o/p: 10
Book a hotel room for  12 dec for 10 member -- o/p: 10 ";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}\nGroup 1: {1}\nGroup: {2}", m.Value, m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

If all the matches are preceded by `for` you might also use

```
\bfor (\d+)\s?(people|members?|employees?)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the number, not capturing much else, maybe you are looking for something like this

```
(?<=for)(?: +)(?<number>\d+)(?= +(?:people|employee|member)s?)
```